# Optimize negate OR and operators query in JavaScript (Filter method)

Tags: javascript

How do we write nodes.filter() function safice the given condition?

```
nodes: [1]
hiddenIds: undefined << This can be dynamically changed.
output => [1]

nodes: [1, 2]
hiddenIds: [2]
output => [1]

nodes: [1, 2]
hiddenIds: undefined
output => [1, 2]

nodes: [1, 2, 3]
hiddenIds: [2]
output => [1,3]
```

Here is my solution and it works; Can anyone optimize this query?

`nodes.filter(id => !hiddenIds || (hiddenIds && !hiddenIds.includes(id)))`

Thanks

Comment: `id => hiddenIds?.includes(id) ?? true`

Comment: `!(hiddenIds || []).includes(id)`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking about working code. Consider asking on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `!hiddenIds` is not fulfilled and control flow gets to the right-side of the `||`, you'll know that `hiddenIds` is truthy, so there's no need to check it again:

```
nodes.filter(id => !hiddenIds || hiddenIds.includes(id))
```

```js
const nodes = [1, 2];
let hiddenIds = [1];

console.log(
  nodes.filter(id => !hiddenIds || hiddenIds.includes(id))
);

hiddenIds = undefined;

console.log(
  nodes.filter(id => !hiddenIds || hiddenIds.includes(id))
);
```

But I'd prefer to only do the filtering in the first place if `hiddenIds` is truthy:

```
const results = hiddenIds
  ? nodes.filter(id => hiddenIds.includes(id))
  : nodes; // or nodes.slice(), if you need a copy
```

```js
const nodes = [1, 2];
let hiddenIds = [1];

console.log(
  hiddenIds
    ? nodes.filter(id => hiddenIds.includes(id))
    : nodes
);

hiddenIds = undefined;

console.log(
  hiddenIds
    ? nodes.filter(id => hiddenIds.includes(id))
    : nodes
);
```

Comment: Works fine here, both snippets produce the expected result